# How can I "safely" change UIWindow frame?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Background: I'm struggling to create an additional status bar (implemented as a new UIWindow) that is temporarly displayed under the status bar.

To achive that I'm offseting app's keyWindow down by 20px:
(0 20; 320 460) -> (0 40; 320 440)
and then back 20px up:
(0 40; 320 440) -> (0 20; 320 460)
So far everything works as expected, the keyWindow is moved down and then up. Great!

Next, I'm changing keyWindow's rootViewController from a one that wantsFullScreenLayout (UINavCtrl) to a one that doesn't (a plain UIViewCtrl). Here comes the problem, the key window is moved by 20px down. Why??? ;(

I did few tests and it looks like "normally" the system resizes keyWindow's frame when a rootViewController changes from a one that wantsFullScreenLayout to a one that doesn't (and vice-versa) - awesome! However, once the key window frame has been changed "manually" this OS-based auto layout seems to be disabled even though the frame before the rootViewController change is exactly the same as it would be when set by the OS (or just "untouched" in other words). :/

Comment: Consider doing the same thing with UIViews, this will make the process a whole lot easier, and should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but since I'm switching root view controllers and using different kind of navigations it won't be that much easier. Plus, it would be more "messy".

Comment: No, it's a XIB-less app, everything is done programatically.